# Setting windows' position / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to set position of the window on 550px from top.

```
<script>$(document).ready(function(){window.scroll(0,550);});</script>
```

I wrote this and turned out that page jumps to the end and goes back to top.

What is wrong with this code? Should I make it different way?

Comment: What do you mean by "setting the window position"? Do you want to scroll, or to move the actual window?

Comment: What other technologies are you using?  (eg asp.net?)  Do you have an anchor ("#" in the url/address bar)?  Please read this [mcve] - particularly the *verifiable* part.  The code provided scrolls down fine (try it in the console of this window).  So there *must* be something else scrolling to the top.

Comment: I want to move the actual window 550px down. Im using php. Ok so i have to review the earlier code

Comment: You can't move the window.  `scroll` scrolls it down.

Comment: Works fine for me ... https://jsfiddle.net/9dz4ke7L/ ... Maybe it's something else on your code

Comment: Are you importing jQuery correctly? It's working fine for me. Check this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/q5onF0sqZbRHE6L6p2UD

Comment: @WaldirJ.PereiraJunior if jquery wasn't included, it wouldn't move down at all

Comment: Oh yeah. That's right.. Could you write a plunker to simulate the problem?

Comment: If you want to move browser window to some position on a screen there is [window.moveTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/moveTo). But this functionality is very restricted.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
$('html,body').scrollTop(550)
```